# Put the content of a Blade section in a variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In my blade template, there is a simple section :

```
@section('container')
My html markup here
@stop
```

that I call in a "master.blade.php" file :

```
@yield('container')
```

As I could understand, the `yield` function print the content of `container`. But I would like to know if I can put the content of container in a variable instead of ?

I would like to do something like that :

```
$myvar = @yield('container');
```

I know it is not correct syntaxically but there is the idea. I want to put the content of the section `container` in a variable.

Comment: Meaning you want to put just "My html markup here" in a variable, or the entire container markup (including `@section('container')` and `@stop`)?

Comment: I just want to put "My html markup here" in a variable.

Comment: you can use view composer to pass variable to views. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers

Answer (score 1):

When returning the view, read the html markup from a file and use `with`:

```
$html = File::get($filepath);
return view('yourview')->with(compact('html'));
```

Then in your Blade view file you can just [output it](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures) like so:

```
@section('container')
    {{ html }}
@stop
```

You can read more on in the [Laravel Views Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views)

Comment: Your trick only works if the html markup is small. But, I have a full HTML page in my "container" section, I can't use your solution...

Comment: What error are you getting?  A string can be as large as 2gb.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @user3158900 Yes, but that won't be practical to put a full HTML page in a PHP variable...

Comment: You could store it in a different file, load it from there and return it with the view. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Then you'll need to give more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some javascript to do something like this:

```
var somvar = $("#container").html();
```

or something like this:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div>Contents goes <b>here</b></div>
<?php $contents = ob_get_contents(); ?>
```

Comment: The second method would help you I guess.

Comment: I know the ob_start option and I already used it, but I would like to know if a Laravel solution exists...

Comment: Frankly Blade is just a rendering machine, I'm afraid their won't be a way to assign variables in the rendering machines.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be in the view?  Can you do something like...

```
$myvar = View::make('yourview.blade.php')->with('somevars');
```